# Decomposing into multiple of divisors

Tags: algorithms

I have a number x. I know its prime factors and their multiplicity. Does anyone know an algorithm that decomposes it into all possible combination of its divisors (without respect to order)?

E.g. x=18 (prime factor , multiplicity): (2,1), (3,2)

Decompositions: (18) (1,18) (2,9) (3,6) (1,2,9) (1,3,6) (2,3,3) (1,2,3,3)

An algorithm that doesn't take into account 1 and x itself (giving (2,9) (3,6)  (2,3,3 ) would also be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is effectively partitioning a multiset of prime factors.

The simple algorithm to partition an integer is via a recursive function which takes as parameters the value remaining to partition, the maximum part, and suitable accumulator(s). E.g. if the handling of the final partition is done with a `visit` function then

```
_partitionInteger(int n, int maxPart, int[] accum)
    if (n == 0) visit(accum)
    else for (int m = 1; m <= maxPart; m++) _partitionInteger(n - m, m, accum :: m)
```

This is then wrapped for nice presentation as

```
partitionInteger(int n)
    _partitionInteger(n, n, [])
```

Exactly the same approach works here. The difference is that instead of dealing with integers we're dealing with multisets. Instead of `n == 0` we want to test `t == {}`, and instead of iterating from `1` to `maxPart` we need to iterate over multisets in lexicographic order. It will be easiest to represent them in frequency notation with an order of parts: for your application, that means that each multiset is an ordered sequence of prime powers. If the argument `n` has its first non-zero value at position `i` then the multisets `m` over which we iterate must have a non-zero value at position `i`: otherwise we'll never terminate. (This is analogous to starting the iteration at `m = 1` instead of `m = 0`).

So to take your example of `18 = 2^1 3^2`, the recursive calls are:

```
_partition({2:1, 3:2}, {2:1, 3:2}, [])
    _partition({2:0, 3:2}, {2:1, 3:0}, [{2:1, 3:0}])
        _partition({2:0, 3:1}, {2:0, 3:1}, [{2:1, 3:0}, {2:0, 3:1}])
            _partition({2:0, 3:0}, {2:0, 3:1}, [{2:1, 3:0}, {2:0, 3:1}, {2:0, 3:1}])
                visit([{2:1, 3:0}, {2:0, 3:1}, {2:0, 3:1}])
        _partition({2:0, 3:0}, {2:0, 3:2}, [{2:1, 3:0}, {2:0, 3:2}])
            visit([{2:1, 3:0}, {2:0, 3:2}])
    _partition({2:0, 3:1}, {2:1, 3:1}, [{2:1, 3:1}])
        _partition({2:0, 3:0}, {2:0, 3:1}, [{2:1, 3:1}, {2:0, 3:1}])
            visit([{2:1, 3:1}, {2:0, 3:1}])
    _partition({2:0, 3:0}, {2:1, 3:2}, [{2:1, 3:2}])
        visit([{2:1, 3:2}])
```

Actually writing out the details gets a bit messier, but e.g. in Python we get:

```python
def partitionFactors(n):
    primes, powers, p = [], [], 2
    while p * p <= n:
        pow = 0
        while n % p == 0:
            n /= p
            pow += 1
        if pow > 0:
            primes.append(p)
            powers.append(pow)
        p += 1 + (p & 1)
    if n > 1:
        primes.append(n)
        powers.append(1)
    return partitionFactorsImpl(primes, powers, list(powers), [])

def partitionFactorsImpl(primes, powers, max, accum):
    curr, firstIdx = [0] * len(primes), 0
    while firstIdx < len(primes) and powers[firstIdx] == 0:
        firstIdx += 1

    if firstIdx == len(primes):
        yield list(accum)
        return

    curr[firstIdx] = 1
    while True:
        i, factor = firstIdx, 1
        while i < len(powers):
            factor *= int(primes[i] ** curr[i])
            powers[i] -= curr[i]
            i += 1

        accum.append(factor)
        for partition in partitionFactorsImpl(primes, powers, curr, accum):
            yield partition
        accum.pop()

        i = firstIdx
        while i < len(powers):
            powers[i] += curr[i];
            i += 1

        # Advance curr. This is effectively counting in a variable base to avoid exceeding the available powers.
        idx = len(powers) - 1
        while idx >= firstIdx:
            curr[idx] += 1
            if curr[idx] > powers[idx]:
                curr[idx] = 0
                idx -= 1
            else:
                break
        # There are two ways of running out of space
        # Note that the test `curr > max` can probably be optimised
        if idx < firstIdx or curr > max:
            break
```

Sample output:

```
for x in partitionFactors(4 * 9 * 17):
    print (x)
```

gives

```
[2, 2, 3, 3, 17]
[2, 2, 51, 3]
[2, 2, 9, 17]
[2, 2, 153]
[34, 2, 3, 3]
[34, 2, 9]
[6, 2, 3, 17]
[6, 2, 51]
[6, 34, 3]
[6, 6, 17]
[102, 2, 3]
[102, 6]
[18, 2, 17]
[18, 34]
[306, 2]
[4, 3, 3, 17]
[4, 51, 3]
[4, 9, 17]
[4, 153]
[68, 3, 3]
[68, 9]
[12, 3, 17]
[12, 51]
[204, 3]
[36, 17]
[612]
```

(Note that the C# code in an earlier revision of this answer was buggy: the error is in the way `max` is handled).

Comment: I don't know much C#, could you edit the code so that it outputs the resulting partitions (the contents of PartitionFactorsImpl ,so that I can test it for a given n)?

Comment: @Nesa, I tested it with `foreach (var factors in PartitionFactors(4 * 9 * 17)) Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" * ", factors));` But what languages do you know well? I can probably rewrite it in JavaScript, Python, or Java if that helps.

Comment: @Peter_Taylor I know Python, but I only asked for the algorithm so you have already done more than enough. Could you just append the returned list for (4*9*17)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nesa, I realised while walking home that there was a bug, so I've taken the opportunity to port it while fixing the bug. Sometimes code is the best pseudocode.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works seamlessly, I don't yet understand why, but I will try to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

In very general terms:

1. write out all prime factors of the number of interest in a long array or list (i. e. instead of [(2, 3) (5,2)], use [2, 2, 2, 5, 5])
2. map a function over this that returns all possible permutations of this list.
3. (to increase performance, filter out duplicates in the resulting list-of-lists)
4. Map over each of these permuted lists a function that returns all different ways the list can be split. (after the first elem, the second,...  the n-1th)
5. For each split in each permutation, take the product of all factors in the left split, take the product of all factors in the right split.
6. Flatten the final list of list of number-pairs to end up with a list of number pairs that together will form your required number.

Edit: Above algorithm works if you want splits with two numbers. By introducing multiple splits in step 4, you can create the rest of the results.

Comment: Sum all values?  I thought these were factors.

Comment: This seem to be bruteforcing it, I was interested in something that reduces runtime like step 3

Comment: @CandiedOrange: Astutely observed! I've fixed it.

Comment: @Nesa: if you want all solutions, this does mean trying all of them.

Comment: I think Nesa is looking for a way to generate that doesn't produce duplicates.  (2,9) will be generated twice since there are two 3's at different indexes in your factor array whose order doesn't matter to the solution.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, there is another solution which is recursive in nature, although it also enumerates duplicates: 1. start with your desired number and the list of (factor, multiplicity) pairs. 2. For each of the pairs in the list, call the function recursively by taking one of that factor away (and removing the pair from the list if the multiplicity is now 0) and passing the number divided by that factor in as 'desired number'.

Comment: Yes, you will end up with duplicates. I am not sure if there exists a way to remove them, other than filtering them  after having computed all possibilities. I will think about it some more

Answer (score 0):

I will ignore factor 1 because you could add it as many times as you want.

To solve the problem you need a procedure that produces the list of factorizations of N with the additions requirement that all factor are below or equal some max M.

To produce the factorizations of N

- Build the sorted list of divisors.
- Get the largest divisor D.
- produce the list of factorizations of N with factors <= D (see below)

To produce the factorization of N with factors <= M:

- For each divisor D if N with 1 < D <= M  (use the sorted list create before)

  - If D=N, return the factorization (D).
  - else

    - Generate the factorization of N/D with factors <= D  (recursive call)
    - Add factor D at the end of each returned factorization
- collect all factorizations from the loop into a single list and return that.

That could work.  I haven't actually tested it.